Há algum atalho equivalente ao Control + D (Selecionar palavras iguais) do Visual Studio Code no Visual Studio completo?
Fiz uma pesquisa para achar alguma equivalência desse atalho de selecionar múltiplas instâncias da mesma palavra ou seleção atual (Control + D no VSCode), mas sem sucesso.
Vi sugestões como:
Control + Shift + L (remove a linha atual)
Control + Shift + W (não faz nada), que faria mais sentido uma vez que Control + W seleciona a palavra onde o indicador está atualmente.
Se o atalho não existe no VS, há como configurá-lo ou alcançar o mesmo resultado de maneira alternativa sem ter que usar Barra de pesquisa e etc?

Pessoal dá nota negativa e não sinaliza onde errei.
Assim não ajuda nem com o problema e nem como posso melhorar minha forma de perguntar.

Seleciona a palavra e use a combinação de: ALT + SHIFT + .

Também não funcionou. Este aumenta o zoom no código.

Após meu comentário de não ter funcionado, eu atualizei o visual studio e então este comando passou a funcionar.

Podes usar o comando Shift + Alt + .

No comentário do Bruno na minha pergunta, respondi que não funcionava. Dava zoom no código.
Porém após atualizar o Visual Studio, agora funciona utilizando este comando. Creio que seja um novo atalho referente as últimas atualizações. Obrigado.

Utilizando o Visual Studio 2022 atualizado o atalho para isso é Shift + Alt + .
Vi algumas pessoas falando que aumenta o zoom, o atalho para aumentar o zoom também usa o ponto final, mas é Ctrl + Shift + .
Talvez se confundiram ou é porque o Visual Studio mudou os atalhos em alguma atualização recente, mas se o seu estiver atualizado é o atalho que citei.
